# Trouble With "while True" Statement

Tags: python-2.7, random, glob

I am having trouble with the following script.  Everything functions properly for me until getting to **def PlayAndWait(mediafile):**.  I have looked over all code but do not frequently use the while True statement until recently.

```
import xbmc
import time
import os
import time
import glob
import random

xbmc.executebuiltin("SlideShow(/home/pi/pictures)" )

while True:

    time.sleep(60-time.time()%60)

xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Every Minute,Notification!)")

while True:

    time.sleep(360-time.time()%360)

xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Every Five Minutes,Notification!)")

def PlayAndWait(mediafile):

xbmc.executebuiltin("PlayMedia(%s)" % mediafile, True)

while xbmc.Player().isPlaying():

    time.sleep(1.0)

files = glob.glob('/home/pi/videos/*.mov')

if not files:

    filename = random.choice(files)

    if os.path.isfile(filename):

        PlayAndWait(filename)

xbmc.executebuiltin("SlideShow(/home/pi/pictures)")
```

Comment: Why not just use `pass` instead of `time.sleep(1.0)`

Comment: Not familiar how to implement pass instead of time.sleep(1.0)

Comment: Literally just replace `time.sleep(1.0)` with `pass`. That's it

Comment: Thank you.  Will implement tomorrow, however, still unable to get **def PlayAndWait(mediafile):** and below to function.  Perhaps it's an indent error?

Comment: Indentation error indeed. Atleast in the code above. I don't know about your actual file.